Accessing Virtual Directory from Code Behind
In IIS I've created a virtual directory (called WEB1FTP_USERS) that is a UNC to another server. When choosing the Connect As property I chose the admin account we use when logging in to the server and IIS confirmed access.
In code behind I'm using this line to create a path to the folder I want to access, where "Download" is a folder inside the one to which my virtual directory points.
Dim DLPath As String = Server.MapPath("WEB1FTP_USERS") & "\Download\"

But, when I check for a file in that folder using the code below it doesn't exist.
FileInfo = New FileInfo(DLFilename)
If FileInfo.Exists Then

If I display variable DLFilename on the web page it is exactly right, yet FileInfo is saying it doesn't exist.
What am I missing?

Virtual directory is a web serve concept, https://learn.microsoft.com/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis. So your code won't work as FileInfo wants a file path from the real file system.

@LexLi, since OP is using MapPath() he might be aware of that. However it's unclear if he mapped to the actual remote WEB1FTP_USERS in IIS, or just created a virtual folder with that name.

In IIS, off of my web app, I created the virtual folder, the dialog's "Alias" field has the name in my MapPath statement, WEB1FTP_USERS. The "Physical path" is the same UNC I would put in the Explorer to view WEB1 from my hosting server,  \web1\FTP_USERS. Since FileInfo just takes a string, I thought all I needed was the same type of UNC that allows me to explore when logged into the hosting server. But maybe IIS doesn't "resolve" (might be the wrong term) that UNC? As I mentioned, if I display the variable passed to FileInfo it's a correct UNC filename. I'll check that link out. Thnx

Please make sure the file path you are checking in the FileInfo object is the full path, not the virtual directory path. you can try to combine the UNC path and filename.

@meiquan: I'm not sure what you mean by full path versus virtual path. I was using the MapPath to build a string that was a full unc path. If I take that path I'm using and paste it into the the explorer it opens the file, so the string going to FileInfo is correct as best as I can tell.

You can use this code as a reference: Dim DLFilename As String = "\UNC_PATH_TO_SERVER\WEB1FTP_USERS\Download" & "yourfile.ext"
Dim FileInfo = New FileInfo(DLFilename)
If FileInfo.Exists Then
' File exists, proceed with your logic
End If

One thing is you should skip the File.Exists() test completely, and just try to transmit the file directly blind. Really. Then have a try/catch if there's a problem. You need the try/catch anway, thanks to other issues around File.Exists(), and so this will perform better with less code. Unfortunately, this is unlikely to fix your issue. But you might at least get a better error, since unc permissions is one of the many areas where File.Exists() is weak.

Keep in mind the two ways that IIS and your code behind deals with files.
If you map some folder - even a shared UNC path name to say some other server, then when a user types in a URL, then that virtual folder is mapped to the web site.
Thus, a valid URL path name would/could be:
www.example.com/WEB1FTP_USERS/Download/mydoc.pdf

So, any user can type in that valid path name.
And just like ANY folder, they can be secured based on the user's logon.
However, code behind 100% ignores the web site security settings.
So, your code looks correct, and will produce a correct and simple and valid windows path name to the file.
Hence, as you note, the path name returned is correct.
However, code behind when accessing the file (not IIS via a URL), then the security context is now for code behind, and the IIS security is 100% ignored.
In fact, for user files, and for security, we in most cases do NOT use a virtual folder, since then any user can type in a valid path name, including ones that would point to files that don't belong to the current user.
Hence, to present download files for a given user, then we use code behind, and read + stream out the given file (using transmit file).
Hence this:
    Dim strServerFile As String = Server.MapPath($"~/UpLoadFiles/{strFile}")

    If File.Exists(strServerFile) Then

        Response.Clear()
        Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(strFile)
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFile)
        Response.TransmitFile(strServerFile)
        Response.End()

    End If

So, that means we NEVER map with a virtual folder to the files in question, and thus some URL can never by accident or intention get to the files folder. This greatly enhances security of your files.
Regardless, just keep in mind that you might secure a folder using IIS security (based on the user's membership in a security group), but code behind 100% ignores that setting.
What this means at the end of the day is that the security context of the app pool in use (II_USER) will determine if you can read files in that folder using a standard windows valid path AND WHEN running code behind.
You don't mention if the shared folder is secured by domain or not? If yes, then you can add the folder rights to the app pool user context (that the code behind run as).
However, in most cases, what we do is create a new user logon (one on that server, and NOT a domain user). We then create a new user on the server where that folder resides. (same name, same password).
You then (if you still want) use that user + password when setting up the virtual folder (as noted, we don't do this for reasons of security). We then set the app pool user to that same user.
Hence this app pool user:

So, on that shared UNC path server, create the user, and then create the same user (same password) on the IIS server, and thus when code behind runs, it will have rights to that folder. As noted, it not clear if that 2nd server with the path name for files is on a domain or not. (However, with the above approach, it will not matter if you using a domain anyway, since we created a user on both the IIS server, and the other server with that shared folder. As long as both servers have that created user, then accessing files with code behind should work just fine.

Thanks, Albert, much appreciated. I'll be looking into creating accounts on both servers. I am using transmit to send the files for download. I'm looking to access the other server from code behind because we have VBA code that prepares the files for download, generating an email to the client with a temporary username and password. So, if I can leave those things still using the folders on that other server that's best.

Related to these permissions things, I think: I'm now trying to update a database to track when people login, but I'm getting an error "ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Operation must use an updateable query" when trying to write records to the database. Might this be a permissions problem with the app pool? Is this a normal app pool thing, that there's not write access to the local drive / web app's folder? Thanks

It's assumed your database connection is working, and that is a VAST VAST different question and issue.  So are you using SQL logons, or windows authenticated logons for the instance of SQL server? If using SQL logons, then the app-pool user will not matter at all. So, we assume you added both a SQL logon, and a SQL user (you need both for this to work). Even in domain controlled environments, we still very often use a SQL logon, and not a windows/domain logon.  I thus recommend then using a SQL logon. And since you using transmit file, then no need for a virtual folder then, right?

and I see you using Access database, while not recommend for a web site, then you need to force your site to run as x32 bits, or x64 bits depending on what version of Access you installed on the server. In other words, don't use ANY CPU for the site, but force/set the project to run as the same bit size of access having been installed. (so the bit size of Access and what you force the project to run as matters huge here - as I stated, a database question is a VAST different and topic here.

This just keeps getting me deeper and deeper in over my head. I'm stuck with the Access DB for now, per my previous it's used elsewhere in the operation with VBA. I'm not even sure what you mean by SQL or Windows logon. :o/ I'm using ODBC and the app's data source in IIS starts with ".\SQLEXPRESS", so maybe SQL? I'm able to read from the database but unable to add records to it. Not sure where I'll go from here. Was hoping it was permissions that I might learn about along with the other permissions stuff. Oy. Thanks very much, again, for your time Albert.

I had assumed you using SQL server.  Using Access is not really a huge deal, and as I stated, the ONLY real issues are: do you have the Access database engine installed on the server? What version of Access data engine do you have installed? (x32 bits, or x64 bits)?  So, if using a accDB file format, then you using what is called the ACE data engine, but if you still using mdb file formats, then can be using the older JET data engine which ONLY works with mdb files and ONLY comes in x32 bits flavor. You ALWAYS thus must force the .net project match the bit size of Access you are running.

Since you using Access, then the issue of the SQL server logon type does not matter, and can't matter, then right? Only issue then becomes where have you placed (what location) is the Access database? As a general rule, it should thus reside in the app_data folder, but it does not have to.  So 100% ignore my narrative about SQL logons, since you not using SQL server, and that narrative does not apply. I mean, if you not able to connect to Access, then start a new question, since that is a Mount Everest of a different question and different topic from the above question.

Yep, it's an MDB file, using 64 bit both on the server and on the workstation where I'm doing the dev, with the Visual Studio project set to 64 bit. I AM ABLE TO READ THE DATABASE, both in Visual Studio during dev AND on the server. But, I'm only able to WRITE to the database when running in Visual Studio, so I think that means the code I'm using to write to the database is OK. But I'm getting the above-mentioned "updateable query" error after publishing to and running on the server.

I initially didn’t have the mdb file in app_data, but I have already tried moving it there but got the same "updateable query" error when running on the server. I tried adding app pool permissions to the app_data folder by searching IIS AppPool\[App pool name] in the “Select Users...” security dialog, but no matter how I searched I was getting object can’t be found. Do you think lack of app pool permissions is why I can’t write to the database on the server? Thanks again.
